# ios make universal links open only from specific websites

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I implemented universal link to my iOS app. It directs user to application if url has this "www.websiteurl.com/suburl/*.com" pattern. 
I want this work only if user click this url from google search result. If user is already in website I want to open url in website either not open the application. How can I prevent it?

edit: I implemented [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) documentation.

Comment: Will please show the code how you make www.websiteurl.com/suburl/ url to open app ?

Comment: Answer below will work if you have control over link click-site. If user tapped on your link in third party website, or typed link to browser address bar this is will not help you. Your App will handle those clicks.
I assume you have some goal/context behind your question. If you can share that, there is better you get useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but I don't recommend it. If the user has the app installed, it seems like you should want to open the app as soon as possible since it is a much better experience. Anyways, here's my solution.

### Option 1

Short answer: **Wrap your website links in javascript**

Why? according to the Apple standards of Universal Links, a link must be **clicked on** by a user to trigger the Universal Link, therefore if you set up all of your links on your website to be handled by javascript, the app will never open from inside your website.

Therefore, change

```
<a href="www.universal-link-example.com">Link</a>
```

Into a javascript call

```
<a href="javascript:clickLink(www.universal-link-example.com)">Link</a>
```

And open the link from javascript

```
function clickLink(link) {
    window.open(link);
}
```

### Option 2 (Better option)

Use a third-party like [Branch](http://branch.io) links for all of your deep linking so that you can pass more context from web to app allowing the user to continue the same experience on mobile that they were just having on the web. Native is a much better experience 99.9% of the time and it converts users at a much higher rate than web.